# Commands after docker run doesn't execute in bash script

Tags: bash, docker

I have a bash script as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash

  if [ $1 = "first" ]
    then
      cd /Users/sulekahelmini/Documents/fyp/fyp_work/demo/target && docker build . -t suleka96/factorial
  fi
  docker run --rm --name factorialorialContainer -p 8080:8080 -e JAVA_OPTIONS="$(cat /Users/sulekahelmini/Documents/fyp/fyp_work/MLscripts/flags.txt)" suleka96/factorial:latest
  sleep 3
  #run test
  cd /Users/sulekahelmini/Documents/fyp/apache-jmeter-5.2.1/bin && sh jmeter -n -t /Users/sulekahelmini/Documents/fyp/jmeter_scripts/factorial.jmx -l /Users/sulekahelmini/Documents/fyp/fyp_work/MLscripts/jmeter_results.jtl
  #convert result to csv
  cd /Users/sulekahelmini/Documents/fyp/apache-jmeter-5.2.1/bin && ./JMeterPluginsCMD.sh --generate-csv /Users/sulekahelmini/Documents/fyp/fyp_work/MLscripts/agg_test.csv --input-jtl /Users/sulekahelmini/Documents/fyp/fyp_work/MLscripts/jmeter_results.jtl --plugin-type AggregateReport
  docker stop factorialorialContainer
```

when I run this script using:

> sudo ./microwise.sh two

It starts the container and prints the starting of the spring framework and other information in the terminal. The problem is that the next two lines (executing jmeter test and getting results into a csv) after docker run doesn't get executed.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @sulekha_28 run docker in the background with `-d` option `docker run --rm --name factorialorialContainer -p 8080:8080 -d -e JAVA_OPTIONS="$(cat /Users/sulekahelmini/Documents/fyp/fyp_work/MLscripts/flags.txt)" suleka96/factorial:latest`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this is because your container is still running in foreground, so you need to add `-d` flag after `docker run` so it will detach the console and run it in background.